# Setting Javascript var with string[] array values from controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC app. In one of the views, I am trying to set the value of a Javascript var based on a static controller method, which returns an string[].

I've used hard-coded values to confirm that the controller method is getting invoked and returning the correct values.

In Javascript:

```
    var countries = @MyApp.Web.Controllers.DataController.GetCountries();
```

In controller (C#):

```
    public static string[] GetCountries()
    {
        string[] countries = { "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Zimbabwe" };
        return countries;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Please note I do not want to use Ajax.

Comment: Did you look at the generated code? The problem will be obvious.

Comment: Side note: ViewBag would be a better spot to put `countries` into, and to read from in the view.

Comment: @CrescentFresh, I get what the problem is. My specific question is how to change the Javascript code to get the *value* of the array returned.